# Find structurally catch blocks in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I need to find all `catch` blocks with one-letter catch parameters in Java code, for example:

```
catch (IOException e)
```

I've tried the following pattern and it doesn't work:

```
catch ($Type$ $name$)

$name$ text/regexp set to `.`
```

Comment: Maybe ``.{1}``? What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: It doesn't find anything in the project while I have a lot of code that should match. `.{1}` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible solution 1

Try the existing template *try's*. Edit variable `$ExceptionDcl$` to text/regexp `.` and enable *This variable is target of the search*. Try statements with multiple catch blocks will only be found once with this pattern.

## Possible solution 2

To find individual catch blocks in try statements with multiple catches use:

```
$E$ $e$
```

$E$ Text/regexp: `Throwable`, *Apply constraint within type hierarchy* enabled
$e$ Text/regexp: `.`, Script text: `__context__.parent instanceof com.intellij.psi.PsiCatchSection`

## Background info

It is not possible to search for lonely catch blocks. To search a language Structural Search uses the parser that is used for all other smartness in IntelliJ IDEA. This means that every pattern must be valid Java when searching for Java. Thus it is an unfortunate limitation that just a catch block is not parsed into something that can be searched for. This is also why it is not possible replace keywords with a $variable$ in an SSR pattern.